# JavaSsist: toBytecode() throws exception java.lang.RuntimeException: remaper.by.moofMonkey.Main class is frozen but him isn't frozen

Tags: java, class, javassist

If I calling toBytecode() method in my context it throws

> java.lang.RuntimeException: remaper.by.moofMonkey.Main class is frozen
>           at javassist.CtClassType.checkModify(CtClassType.java:515)
>           at javassist.CtClass.getClassFile(CtClass.java:524)
>           at com.moofMonkey.Main.writeFile(Main.java:340)
>           at com.moofMonkey.Main.saveClasses(Main.java:324)
>           at com.moofMonkey.Main.main(Main.java:309)

My context:

```
.....
for (CtClass cl : modClasses) {
    cl.stopPruning(true);
    writeFile(cl, "./ModifiedClasses"); //cl.writeFile("./ModifiedClasses");
    cl.stopPruning(false);
}
.....
public static void writeFile(CtClass cl, String directoryName) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(">> " + cl.getName());

    byte[] bc = cl.toBytecode();

    String s = cl.getClassFile().getSourceFile();
    int index = new String(bc).indexOf(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)  //KILL SOURCEFILE (c) moofMonkey
        bc[index + i] = '-';

    DataOutputStream out = cl.makeFileOutput(directoryName);

    out.write(bc);

    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

BUT... But. If I calling analog of writeFile() - cl.writeFile() - all works!

I can do this:

```
1. Save File
2. Read bytes from him
3. Dp what I need
4. Save File
```

Comment: Q Solved. Special thanks for @SubOptimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look into the javadoc of [CtClass](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#toBytecode--) reveals

> Once this method is called, **further modifications are not possible** any more.

If you change the call order to

```
String s = cl.getClassFile().getSourceFile();
byte[] bc = cl.toBytecode();
```

you can call `toBytecode`.

Comment: Not enough documentation - please note this in the future :3
Most people love docs and don't love copy-paste. Sorry.

Comment: @moofMonkey `Most people love docs` those are the ones which find such a solution themself. ;-)

Comment: this is useful :-)

Comment: reload page :3 U're in top!)

Answer (score 0):

The exception isn't coming where you call `toBytecode` but in the next source line, where you call `getClassFile`. The [documentation](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/index.html) says that you aren't allowed to call this on a frozen class.

There's a method called `getClassFile2` which seems intended to work around this problem:

> Returns a class file for this class (read only). Normal applications do not need calling this method. Use getClassFile().
>
> The ClassFile object obtained by this method is read only. Changes to this object might not be reflected on a class file generated by toBytecode(), toClass(), etc.
>
> This method is available even if isFrozen() is true. However, if the class is frozen, it might be also pruned.

The first paragraph suggests that if there's some way to restructure your code so it doesn't need to get a class file for a frozen class, that might be better (or at least better-thought-of by the creators of Javassist).